# Web scraping Python script doesn't give error OR result. Is it a requests issue or an XPATH issue?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, python-requests, reminders

I've wrote (pieced together) a script with the goal of scraping an online schedule and making desktop reminders based on it. The actual scraping function doesn't give me an error OR result. It seems to be working, but not working. Is it an XPATH issue or have I got the actual HTML connection part wrong?

The first issue was an SSL error that I had to play with until it stopped giving an issue. I fixed that. Now it runs successfully but only shows empty brackets as the result.

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import ssl
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
payload = { 'username': 'u1000', 'password': 'p1000' }
url = 'https://login.url'
requests.post(url, data=payload, verify=False)

page = requests.get('https://schedule.url', verify=False)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

first_appt = tree.xpath('//*[@id="workarea"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]')

print('First Appt: ', first_appt)
#NO ERRORS BUT NO RESULTS
```

The URLs have been changed for client's privacy. I got the XPATH for the text I need to scrape via INSPECT>COPY XPATH in Chrome. There's up to 9 time frames I'm aiming to scrape and the only difference between the XPATH are the "tr[#]" at the end of the XPATH. It increments by one for each appointment. I expected this script to connect, login, find the XPATH and scrape the text.
Instead, it gives:

```
"First Appt: []"
```

As suggested, changed code to the following:

```
from lxml import etree, html
import requests
import ssl
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
payload = { 'username': 'u1000', 'password': 'p1000' }
url = 'https://login.url'
requests.post(url, data=payload, verify=False)

sess = requests.Session()
sess.post(url, data=payload, verify=False)

page = requests.get('https://schedule.url', verify=False)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
tree = etree.ElementTree(tree)

#first_appt = tree.xpath('//*[@id="workarea"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]')
#first_appt = tree.xpath('//*[@id="workarea"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td')
#first_appt = tree.xpath('//*[@id="workarea"]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/b') < TOP DATE
first_appt = tree.xpath('//*[@id="plid10575"]/div[2]')
print('First Appt: ', first_appt)
```

Altered code ran without error, however, same result. Using different XPaths didn't change result, leading me to believe either my understanding on xpath is wrong or my method of identifying the required xpath is wrong.
Changing:

```
print('First Appt: ', first_appt)
```

to

```
print(tree)
```

was the only different result, which produced:

```
# $ py login.py
# <lxml.etree._ElementTree object at 0x04288BE8>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I would first check what's there in `tree`? is it holding the page source or empty.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome. I’m not sure if I’m addressing that part correctly. I used chrome inspect>copy xpath for a google button and used the google url (in a stripped down version) but it returned the same empty result.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue is that return from the POST request to the login url is not being stored anywhere.  This line:

```
requests.post(url, data=payload, verify=False)
```

has you logging in, but the fact that have logged in is not saved anywhere.  Web servers (mostly) are stateless.  They don't remember who has logged in and how hasn't.  This is where a session comes into play.  When you send a POST request, the server responds by saying "hey there, i know who you are, here is some additional stuff you can show me from now on that proves that i know you."  What it sends back is a cookie.

In a browser that cookie is automatically saved.  What you are doing in Python is asking for a cookie using your POST request, but not storing it in a way such that future requests use that cookie to show you have been authenticated.

This is where a `Session` object comes into play.  You can make `GET` and `POST` requests from a `Session` object, and it will store and handles all of the administrative stuff like cookies for you.

Try this:

```
sess = requests.Session()
sess.post(url, data=payload, verify=False)

page = requests.get('https://schedule.url', verify=False)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
```

Comment: But when you do a request, it's automatically created a session on `request` method, there's some difference creating a instance of `sess = requests.Session()` and after call `session.post`?

Comment: Calling `requests.post` does not store the response from the server (cookie) for future use.  So when you later call `requests.get`, it is like you never logged in.

Comment: Okay, this (and everybody's feedback) definitely seems to address my issue. I will work with it when I'm off work tonight and update everybody asap. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, made suggested changes. Result still the same. Interesting note: I changed the xpath to different parts of the site with no difference. Editing original question to include results.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check what is in page.content? Apart from what James has suggested, try converting tree to ElementTree:

```
from lxml import etree, html

tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
tree = etree.ElementTree(tree)
```

Also, include text() in the XPATH

```
first_appt = tree.xpath('//*[@id="plid10575"]/div[2]text()')
```

Comment: Assuming I understood this suggestion, it produced:
`<lxml.etree._ElementTree object at 0x04288BE8>`

Comment: Result (on several different XPATH attempts)
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "login.py", line 18, in <module>
    first_appt = tree.xpath('//*[@id="workarea"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]text()')
  File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 2287, in lxml.etree._ElementTree.xpath
  File "src\lxml\xpath.pxi", line 359, in lxml.etree.XPathDocumentEvaluator.__call__
  File "src\lxml\xpath.pxi", line 227, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result
lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression`

Answer (score 0):

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import ssl
import urllib3

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

payload = { 'username': 'u1000', 'password': 'p1000' }
url = 'https://login.url'
requests.post(url, data=payload, verify=False)

page = requests.get('https://schedule.url', verify=False)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

rows = []
tables = soup.find_all("table")
for table in tables:
    rows = table.find_all("tr")
    for row in rows:
        data = row.find_all("td")
        r = [i.text for i in data]
        rows.append(r)

print('First Appt: ', rows)
```